# Quiero que mi programa me responda en base a cada uno de los casos (Simulador de precios de autos

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un trabajo sencillo para el colegio, mi pregunta es, ¿como hago que mi programa responda en base a la eleccion de uno de los 3 casos?

lo que quiero es que en el `cout` despues de los dos puntos diga el precio del automovil seleccionado pero no se como hacerlo

ejemplo, si selecciono el auto 1 quiero que me de su precio que seria la `const float precio_gt=4538900`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int auto_1;
   int precio_t;
   const float precio_gt= 4538900;
   const float precio_e=1211900;
   const float precio_gt4=2459900;
   const float margen= 0.20;

   cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t M E R C E D E Z  B E N Z" <<endl;
   cout << "\t\t\t\t\t        Ver. 1.0.0";
   cout << "\n\n\t puedes elegir entre estas opciones:" <<endl;
   cout << "\n\t\t 1) Mercedez Benz-AMG GT" <<endl<<endl;
   cout << "\n\t\t 2) Mercedez Benz Clase E Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
   cout << "\n\t\t 3) Mercedez Benz-AMG GT 4-Door Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
   cout << "\t Ingrese el numero del auto que selecciono: ";
   cin >> auto_1;

   switch (auto_1)
   {
   case 1: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto Mercedez Benz-AMG GT" <<endl<<endl;
   break;
   case 2: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto Mercedez Benz Clase E Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
   break;
   case 3: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto Mercedez Benz-AMG GT 4-Door Coupe" <<endl<<endl;
   break;
   default: cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha ingresado una opción incorrecta" <<endl<<endl;
   }
   cout << "\t El valor del auto que selecciono es de: "<<case 1" ";

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es formaciones de datos.

```
float precios[3] {4538900, 1211900, 2459900};
std::string nombres[3] {"Mercedez Benz-AMG GT", "Mercedez Benz Clase E Coupe", "Mercedez Benz-AMG GT 4-Door Coupe"};

int auto_1;
std::cin >> auto_1;

if (auto_1 >= 0 && auto_1 <= 2)
    std::cout << "\n\n\t Usted ha seleccionado el auto " nombres[auto_1]
              << "\t El valor del auto que selecciono es de: " << precios[auto_1];
```